# Trouble calling NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, swift

I've managed to create my `UICollectionViewController` with swift, and implement the `NSFetchedResultsController` and fetch stuff from my CoreData model. All good there... But...
I can't seem to call any of the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods from within my extension. Code is as follows:

```
extension MainsViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    func fetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {

    //        if(fetchedResultsController != nil){
    //            return fetchedResultsController()
    //        }
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = RKObjectManager.sharedManager().managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext

    var entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Dessert", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    fetchRequest.entity = entity
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    var sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    fetchedResultsController().delegate = self

    var aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")

    var error: NSError?
    if !aFetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error){
        println("An error:\(error) occured.")
    }



    return aFetchedResultsController
}

//Here is where i would call *@optional func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController!)* etc. etc.

}
```

But swift doesnt recognise theese methods. I can't figure out what it is I am missing.

Would be great if someone could help me out.

Thanks in advance

Chris

Comment: I have the same problem with the UITextFieldDelegate. I write the protocol in the class declaration and swift does not recognize the delegate-methods... I thought it was a bug in xCode 6 Beta.
I see nothing special in you code except this:
fetchedResultsController().delegate = self
i would write it to
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

Comment: For some reason it will not let me set the delegate of my fetchedResultsController either way. It says `NSFetchedResultsController does not have a member named delegate`

Comment: Why is your ViewController even an extension? Doesn't it makes more sense to create it as a class? So class MainsViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {...}?

Comment: @BenjaminHerzog `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` is an extension of my `MainsViewController` ( [Swift: Extension Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-XID_193) ). I might have gotten that the wrong way around, but I think that is how it is done (if you wan't to make an extension, that is)

Comment: You use an extension to extend existing classes or protocolls. So in this case you need to have a class or protocol that's named MainsViewController and you extend it to react to the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.
Does I get it right?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean! Cheers for picking that up!

Comment: Does it effect your problem in any way?

Comment: No luck unfortunately

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. You want to lazy-set the property of the fetchedResultsController. I create an answer for that, one moment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it was simply the auto complete feature that wasn't suggesting the method to me. Typing it out manually 'fixed' the issue. Sorry for wasting everybody's time...

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I think it should something like this:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
        get {
            var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

            var context: NSManagedObjectContext = RKObjectManager.sharedManager().managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext

            var entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Dessert", inManagedObjectContext: context)

            fetchRequest.entity = entity
            fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

            var sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false)
            let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
            self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

            var aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")

            var error: NSError?
            if !aFetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error){
                println("An error:\(error) occured.")
            }
            return aFetchedResultsController
        }
    }
```

So your MainsViewController is a class, as I said in the comment above, so the first line has to look like this:

```
class MainsViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
```

Unfortunatly I cannot test the code, but this can be understood like this: You have a property called fetchedResultsController and this will execute, when the fetchedResultsController is getting. So in the getter like you would do it in objective-c with a lazy getting method.